# vite proxy does not support post method

Tags: vue.js, post, proxy, vite

I've added these proxy settings in my `vite.config.js`.

```js
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
```

I am trying to solve CORS problem so that I could `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` from `localhost:5173` to `localhost:9000`. With the above changes, when I test the code, I can `GET` resource from `localhost:9000`. However, I cannot post data to `localhost:9000`. It always shows that I am posting  to `localhost:5173`:

[image]

How can I solve this CORS issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The point of a proxy is that it proxies a request from dev server (5173) to api (9000). There's no way how it could appear differently. It works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Solve this problem by adding your client's origin to server's cors-allow-origins.

you can reference Configuration Options of using Frameworks document. For example [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

[image]